# Kubernetes on VSphere

Tags: vmware-vsphere, docker

We are developing a php/mysql app and it will involve lot of apis and be used by a large group of employees however this is not a public facing internet scale website.

We are using containers (Dockers) so we were looking to setup the system so it is ready with HA/LB/Scale ready from the start.

So we evaluated docker swarm but docker seems to have brought a half cooked swarm mode into mix and its needs it time to become stable/usable.

We wanted to try Kubernates and since our servers are all Vmware ESXI , we gave its Vsphere deployment a go but it didn't work as advertised also looking at their github issues it seems like its maintained by a single person so not sure its the way to go.

We are now looking to evaluate the Baremetal kubernates but running them in the VMs instead but we dont see how to setup the loadbalancer?

Is that even possible?

Also do you believe Kubernates going to support vmware/baremetal and other deployments going forward or they are only going to support the GCE/AWS/DO ?

Answer (score 2):

I can't answer for Kubernetes but take a look at [vSphere Integrated Containers](http://cormachogan.com/2016/07/14/getting-started-vsphere-integrated-containers-v0-4-0/), though it's interesting that you may have the same issues with the current state of containerisation in relation to virtualisation that many of us have. VIC is perhaps enough for you for now however.

Answer (score 1):

Kubernetes supports bare metal. They also have documentation for creating a cluster on [vSphere](http://kubernetes.io/docs/getting-started-guides/vsphere/).

Currently in a bare metal/self hosted cluster you don't use the loadBalancer type to expose your services. There is work being done to make it so there is a supported self hosted loadbalancer but nothing as of yet. Instead, when you expose services you can use type: NodePort which will expose your service on all of the nodes in your cluster on a random or specified port. For web services (ports 80 and 443) you would probably want to use an [ingress controller](http://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/ingress/) which can load balance your web services based on the requested hostname of the request header.

Not trying to be too self promoting but I wrote a blog post about exposing services with [on-prem kubernetes clusters](https://medium.com/@rothgar/exposing-services-using-ingress-with-on-prem-kubernetes-clusters-f413d87b6d34#.mwjb685bt). Hopefully it will be useful.